# Добавить и убрать класс к блоку по нажатию

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть контейнера и в каждом из них есть много блоков. Мне надо по нажатию на `div` к примеру по нажатию на `block open0` чтобы ко всем блокам во всех контенерах с классом `block open0` добавился ещё один класс и по нажатию убрался. Помогите пожалуйста

```
<div class="container_first">
    <div class="block open0">

   </div>
   <div class="block open1">

   </div>
   <div class="block open2">

   </div>
</div>

<div class="container_second">
    <div class="block open0">

   </div>
   <div class="block open1">

   </div>
   <div class="block open2">

   </div>
</div>

<div class="container_third">
     <div class="block open0">

   </div>
   <div class="block open1">

   </div>
   <div class="block open2">

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подсказка, `document.querySelectorAll( this.className.match(/open\d+/)[0] )` Хотя если разметка правда такая: У всех строго соответствуют номера, можно воспользоваться индексом, и вообще обойтись без лишних классов. Внутри обработчика клика: `alert( [].indexOf.call( this.parentNode.children, this ) );`

Answer (score 1):

Немножко изврат, но все-же )

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.block').forEach(d => d.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const selector = [...e.target.classList].map(e => `.${e}`).join('')
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(e => e.classList.toggle('active'))
}))
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_first">
  <div class="block open0">
    0
  </div>
  <div class="block open1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="block open2">
    2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_second">
  <div class="block open0">
    0
  </div>
  <div class="block open1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="block open2">
    2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container_third">
  <div class="block open0">
    0
  </div>
  <div class="block open1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="block open2">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```